# Why does Angular JS count wrong clicks?

Tags: angularjs

I have Angular JS code:

```
$scope.click = function (id) {
   notificationsModal.confirm(function () {
     $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log(id);
        if(id == "test"){
           $scope.contacts.blocked = $scope.contacts.blocked + 1;
        }
     });
   }
}
```

When I do click I get confirm JS window with cancel button. I push this button for canceling event. I do this operation 4 ones.

After I confirm message and get 4 outputs `console.log(id);` in console. Why does it work for each click if I did cancel and condition had not been executed?

Comment: the variable `id` might have mutated by the time the callback is called. You should bind id like this `function(x) { }.bind(this,id)` and then use `x`.

Comment: Most confirm functions have a boolean returned ... show us the function declaration. A demo that replicates this would also help

Comment: Can you explain please your comment with `bind`?